# Disabling live-chat on Youtube Live Broadcast using api

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I am asked to toggle `Enable live chat` using the Youtube API.

Digging through the documentation. The closest thing I can find regarding live-chat is: `snippet.liveChatId: The ID for the broadcast's YouTube live chat. With this ID, you can use the liveChatMessage resource's methods to retrieve, insert, or delete chat messages.` (https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.liveChatId)

Anyone knows how to enable/disable live chat through API?

Answer (score -1):

I am also looking for this, but from what I can tell it is currently not available in youtubes public api.